# How to fix this door hinge

Tags: doors, hinges

One of my door hinges came out. Now the hole is loose and the hinge doesn't stay in the hole. Door keeps falling. How do I repair this? If it can be glued, what kind of glue should I use?
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's the material that the hinge sets into (the frame of the door)? Is it hollow, or was that thread meant to hold into a solid material?

Comment: The material of the hinge and the bore is some metal, probably steel. But there are some green layers on exposed metal surface. The bore is threaded inside. But I am not sure if the hinge can be screwed in the bore because it is next to the wall. You can see the vertical line of the corner right next to the bore. This prevents the hinge to be rotated when screwing into the bore.

Comment: ... maybe the pin can be removed, allowing you to screw it into place? I was also wondering if there might have been a nut on the inside at one point...

Answer (score 1):

If it's stripped, and this is only a temporary fix, I've placed wood shaving in the hole in this circumstance and then threaded the bolt into the hole. The shavings tighten the hole.

Comment: I've heard a toothpick or two can also work similarly